# Copying rows from one csv file to another based on a condition in C

Tags: python, c, csv, copy

I intend to copy certain rows from a space-separated CSV file (the format of each row is not very rigid, in terms of the number of spaces separating each column) to another, based on an index array that list down the numbers of the rows to be copied.

In Python (using csv package), I would use something like this:

```
with open("final_shapes.csv", "a") as myfile:
    myfile.write(str([shapes_list[m] for m in range(0, len(x)) if (x[m] == 1)])  + "\n" )
```

I was wondering is there is a way to do this in C (addressing the csv file row-wise, instead of character-wise). Thank you!

Edit: I would prefer not to use new modules, but if it really makes the job easier, so be it.

Edit 2: The CSV file I am reading looks like this (the number of spaces separating no two columns is constant) -

```
1          var_0_9        SB 1.00000000000000e+00     0.00000000e+00     1.00000000e+00    
2          var_0_17       SB 0.00000000000000e+00     0.00000000e+00     1.00000000e+00    
3          var_0_26       MK 1.00000000000000e+00     0.00000000e+00     1.00000000e+00    
4          var_0_34       SB 1.00000000000000e+00     0.00000000e+00     1.00000000e+00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well,

fgets() will read a row from a file, like the csv file.

by keeping track of how many rows have been read and knowing which row numbers to copy, the actual code will be very simple.

The code will need:

a couple of 'FILE * variables, 
calls to 'fopen()' for each of those variables, (be sure to check for fopen() failures),

a loop counter,

a while( fgets(,,) ) to control the loop.

within the loop,

a 'if' to decide if the row is to be copied,

a fwrite() of each row to copy to the output file.

finally, fclose() for each of the FILE * variables.

And finally, a char buffer[###] to use to hold a row

Comment: Thank you! I was trying variants of fscanf() with \n as the separator, but I've been unable to get it. This should work, hopefully!